# Python, Tkinter. How to put a check on the widget ttk.CheckButton?

Tags: tkinter, ttk

ttk version unlike the TC does not support the methods of inter .SELECT()

Comment: Which python version are you using, which platform?

Comment: What does "TC" stand for?

Answer (score 1):

According to [ttk Checkbutton Guide](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Checkbutton.html) which was a quick google search away

> Not supported are the following methods of the Tkinter Checkbutton widget: .deselect(), .flash(), .select(), and .toggle(). To change the state of a checkbutton through program control, use the .set() method of the associated control variable.

There is also `.invoke()` but that will also call the command, therefore you would have to assign the function to command after calling invoke

Answer (score 0):

To create a Checkbutton in Python3 tkinter with ttk:

```
# create the button
self.check_example =  ttk.Checkbutton(self, text = "Checked")
# invoke "checks" the button
self.check_example.invoke()
# grid is one of the ways to display the button
self.check_example.grid(row=2,column=0, sticky=W)
```